# SQL Server Agent Job will not complete, no indication job even started, no error messages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, execution, sql-server-agent

Agent in SQL Server 2016, running on Server 2014.
SSIS project developed in VS 2015, runs as expected.  Single node executes simple SQL.
Package is deployed via DeploymentManifest, deployed to ‘SQL Server’. Deployed package runs as expected when started in Integration Services > Deployed Packages > MSDB

Have created Credential and Proxy, no changes to problem, no error messages, nothing logged.
Run without Credential and Proxy, same outcome.
Package Security ProtectionLevel is EncryptSensitiveWithPassword, have tried other ProtectionLevels with same outcome.

It appears that nothing is even beginning to execute, no error messages, no completion. How to check that package is actually deployed and agent can access?

Comment: Right click on the job and script as create and update your question with that definition please.

Answer (score 0):

I stopped the service that runs agent jobs: "SQL Server Agent". Restarted it with a different logon, a logon that is used to build and deploy the ssis project. Restarted the service.  The original service was run under the "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT" account , which seems to be a default account.